# Tomcat redirection for a Flex/java web app

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat, redirect

Before asking my question, let me explain the context.

**CONTEXT:**
I have a web app created in both Flex and Java using LiveCycle Data Services. 
The application runs on a Tomcat server. 
Let's assume that the context root of the app is /myApp. When loading server:port/myApp, Tomcat loads myApp.html, which is a wrapper for the application.

**REQUIREMENTS:**
In order to load the application in different languages, I need the swf to read some flashvars to set the loading language and other sutff. 
The loading language should be set depending on the url.

**WHAT I'D LIKE TO DO BUT DO NOT KNOW HOW TO:**
I think that I should have different html wrappers for the swf, so that each html wrapper passes different flashvars to the swf. But not having to deploy a war for each language.
The deployed war should then contain myAppFR.html, myAppEN.html, myAppJP.html... Each wrapper pointing to the same swf but passing different flashvars. 
I'd like server:port/myAPP/FR to load myAppFR.html, server:port/myApp/EN should load myAppEN.html, and so on.

I don't know if I'm being clear enough. 
It's not too clear in my head cause I do not really know how to do it, or if it's even possible!

So please, do not hesitate to ask for more details if needed and feel free to give any clue you have :)

Thanks a lot.

(PS: I'm not a Java pro, so if it would be possible, the more detailed the better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it using JS:

```
function getBrowserLangSetting() {
        if(navigator.language)
            return navigator.language

        if(navigator.userLanguage)
            return navigator.userLanguage
}
```

This is enough for me to set the default language.

Answer (score 0):

Are you tracking the user's locale in the session or anything like that? If so, you could use a JSP (or some other dynamic content-generation framework) to emit the  tag including any variables that you'd like -- including the user's language -- and just use the language from the session's Locale.